# Showing data through foreign keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to get some data through relationships and foreign keys but have gotten myself in a tangle.

I have a Batsmen who user can comment on,the comments can also be edited by the users, the comments have their own page aswell with the option to delete or edit the comment. This is where my problem comes, i am trying to show the nationality of the batsmen but can only retrieve the ID of his nationallity and not the name of the country.

Here are my tables

**Batsmen**: ID, Name, bio, Nationality_ID,
**Nationality**: ID, country_name,
**User** ID, name ,
**Comment**: ID, comment, Batsmen_ID, User_ID

My Relationships

Comment:

```
public function batsmen(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Batsmen');
}
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

Controller:

```
   public function show($id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);

        return view('comments.show')->with('comment', $comment);
    }
```

View :

```
<h4>{{$comment->batsmen->Nationality_id}}</h4>
```

So how would i get the country name to display instead of the nationality_ID?

Comment: By reading proper section of [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships), its all there :). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make another `relationship` method on your `Batsman` model class as -

```
public function nationality(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Nationality','Nationality_id');
}
```

And then in your view-

```
<h4>{{$comment->batsmen->nationality->country_name}}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function show($id)
{
   $comment = Comment::with('batsmen')->find($id);

   return view('comments.show')->with('comment', $comment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the relationship between bastman and **nationality**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function nationality(){

       return $this->belongsTo('App\Nationality',Nationality_id,id);
   }
}
```

Then you can easily get his country

```
<h4>{{$comment->batsmen->Nationality->country_name}}</h4>
```